# Java line break in Text node

Tags: java, eclipse, text, xpath, nodes

I'm pulling some text using an xpath and in Firepath, the Location Description is on 4 seperate lines however when I pull the text out, it concatenates it all onto one line. Is there anyway I could seperate these four lines into sepearte strings?

This is wht my xpath.getText() displays:
 `Ax Man Test Branch Ax Man Test Ax Man Tester`

```
<td class="labelFormReq"/>
<td class="labelForm">Location Description:</td>
<td> Ax Man Test Branch  
Ax Man Test
Ax Man
Tester
</td>
```

Comment: You can separate them by using <br/>?

Comment: so what would my code look like?

Comment: This text "Ax Man Test Branch Ax Man Test Ax Man Tester" is read from database?

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
<td class="labelFormReq"/>
<td class="labelForm">Location Description:</td>
<td>Ax Man Test Branch<br/> 
Ax Man Test<br/>
Ax Man<br/>
Tester<br/>
</td>
```

:)

Comment: But i'm a tester not a developer - the code cannot be edited. Is there anyway of getting the sepearte lines out without editing the code?

Answer (score 0):

simply use the `<br />` tag at the point from where you want to break the line.